# Monitoring http request header on a page

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Accessing HTTP Headers in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)
>   [How do I access the HTTP request header fields via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript)

We can use httpwatch on IE or httpfox on Firefox to monitor http activity

If i don't want to use any plugs on browser...

Is it possible to monitor http request header  on a page just by javascript?

Comment: Here's another one on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the JavaScript standard doesn't specify any way to access HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript only runs inside of a webpage. It can't access things like the http headers overall.