# Installing .netframework as prerequisites

Tags: c#

I have a clickonce application, and i'm going to provide a aspx page to the customer where user can install the application. From this aspx page, .Net4.0 framework should be installed after checking the user machine. Is it possible? if so how??.. can anyone clarify it??

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about ClickOnce, but once you get native code running, .NET framework can be silently installed.

Read the command line options passed to the .NET 4 redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTTP_X_CLICKONCESUPPORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636968/detecting-net-version-without-useragent-string) header value to determine .NET support. As such, you can link the user to the installer if that header isn't present.