# Can I use javascript to get a request header in http get request?

Tags: javascript, http, header, request

I want to get a cookie from **http request header** **not set** http request header using javascript. I've found many answer about getting http response header. But none of it mentioned about a request header. Anyway can I get it?

Comment: which header? in general, there's only headers you set, so you should know what you're setting anyway... in short: no, but you shouldn't need one anyway.

Comment: *When* and why do you want to do this? With `XMLHttpRequest`? Pretty sure there's no accessor for *request* headers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript