# How to get the value of request headers in network and output in the DOM or put the value inside a variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript so please bear with me, I would just like to ask if there is a way to get the a certain value in request headers. Say for example I want to get the value of Authorization then store it in a variable so I can output it in the DOM.

please check the link below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access the HTTP request header fields via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript)

Comment: Mate. You already should have that variable inside your js code. How you lunched that request?